# Powershell "screen" - keep the processes running even the connection is dropped?

Tags: powershell

I'm using `enter-pssession` to run scripts on remote servers. So I can login remotely to the servers. Run commands interactively, close the powershell console and later I can reattach the session and check the commands outputs.

Is there a Linux `screen` like functionality in powershell? I cannot use Windows remote desktop to connect the servers.

Comment: Please elaborate on '`screen` like functionality'.

Comment: Just updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Invoke-Command` with `-InDisconnectedSession`, it will start session in asynchronous mode. After you can connect to this session, take data from it, etc. You can read more about this [here.](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-disconnected-remote-sessions/#entering-a-disconnected-session-to-receive-results)

You can create session, disconnect from session, connect back to it.

May be useful for you: `New-PSSessionOption` with `-IdleTimeout`.

`-IdleTimeout`:
Determines how long the session stays open if the remote computer does not receive any communication from the local computer. This includes the heartbeat signal. When the interval expires, the session closes. [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption)

Comment: There is an issue with `new-pssession`. The `invoke-sqlcmd` got anonymous login (double-hop) issue while Windows remote desktop doesn't have it.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 You need to use CredSSP, which is enable by default for remote desktop sessions, but not for PowerShell sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently run into double-hop issues with using PSSessions. What I did to work around that is to create a Session Configuration on the remote server that uses the `-RunAs` parameter to set the credentials that I need the commands on the remote server to be executed as. Then you connect to that session configuration on the remote server, and things should work as expected.

```
$MyCreds = Get-Credential ''
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "My Remote Config" -RunAsCredential $using:MyCreds -Force
} -ComputerName Server01
```

Then once the session configuration exists I can start a session using that config, and the whole double hop issue is null and void.

Now, mind you I do add some additional security, so that other people cannot use my session config, since that config has my credentials cached on the server (encrypted), and if they used that config they could do whatever they wanted as me. So to accomplish that I get my domain account SID, generate a SDDL line, and restrict access to the Session Config to only my account.

```
$Searcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(sAMAccountName=$($Creds.UserName.Split('\')[1]))(objectClass=user))"
$Results=$Searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
$MySID = new-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($Results.objectSid.value,0)|% value
$SDDL = "O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GR;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)(A;;GA;;;$MySID)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)"
$FQDN = $Server.ServerName,$Server.Forest -join '.'
$MySessionName = "DoubleHop-{0}" -f $MyCreds.UserName.Split('\')[1]
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name $using:MySessionName -RunAsCredential $using:MyCreds -Force -SecurityDescriptorSddl $using:SDDL
} -ComputerName $FQDN -ea 4
```